# forkJoin doesn't return any value angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, fork-join

I have a function to read image from disk. This function returns an observable with the image data.

```
readImage(inputValue: any, maxSize: number) : Observable<any> {
    var file:File = inputValue.files[0]; 
    var myReader:FileReader = new FileReader();
    var observable = this.ng2ImgToolsService.resize([file], maxSize, maxSize).flatMap( 
        (result) => {
          return Observable.create((observer) => {
              myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
                observer.next({imageUrl: myReader.result});
                observer.complete();
              }
              myReader.readAsDataURL(result);
           }) 
        }
    )
    return observable
}
```

I want to read two images from the disk in parallel (same file but with different resizing ratio). So, I call this function twice, forkJoin the two observable, and subscribe to it. This executes the `readImage` function twice. However, I don't get any result emitted to the subscriber (`console.log(results)` is not executed). Although, the `next` function is being called by the observable. If I don't use forkJoin and I subscribe to each observable individually, then they do return the value.

```
var obs = [this.readImage(event.target, 1400), this.readImage(event.target, 800)];
Observable.forkJoin(...obs).subscribe(
    (results) => {
        console.log(results);
    },
    (err) => {
        console.log("error loading thumbnail file", err);
        this.showMainSpinner = false;
    }
);
```

Comment: Suggestion: Rule out the underlying systems by replacing call to resize and readAsDataURL with stubs (eg using setTimeout), creating a self-contained example. If forkJoin still doesn't work, post example using pastebin / codebin or something. In either case you're a step closer.

Comment: I instead used the `.zip` operator and everything works fine. Thank you!

Comment: i guess that means ng2ImgToolsService doesnt complete after emitting? i guess flatmap doesnt complete in turn, even if a particular "file stream" does. sort of makes sense but could be nice to know for sure.